# How to print data in column form in Perl?

Tags: perl, output-formatting

I have a program that prints the contents of arrays in rows. I would like it to print each array in a column next to each other.

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @M_array;
my @F_array;

open (my $input, "<", 'ssbn1898.txt');

while ( <$input> ) {

    chomp;

    my ( $name, $id ) = split ( /,/ ); 

    if ( $id eq "M" ) {
        push ( @M_array, $name );
    }
    else {
        push ( @F_array, $name ); 
    }
}
close ( $input );

print "M: @M_array \n"; 
print "F: @F_array \n";
```

Is this possible or am I trying to do something that can't be done?

Desired format:

```
M      F 
Namem1 Namef1 
Namem2 Namef2
```

Comment: Adding the format that you would like as output will help provide better answers.

Comment: I would iike something like

Comment: M  F           
Namem1 Namef1
Namem2   Namef2

Answer (score 3):

You can add whatever separator you would like between your data by using the [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) function, the example below formats the data in your array separated by tabs:

```
...
use List::MoreUtils qw/pairwise/;

my $separator = "\t";
print join($separator, qw(M F)), "\n";
print join(
   "\n", 
   pairwise { ( $a // '') . $separator . ( $b // '') } @M_array, @F_array
), "\n";
...
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `//` is perl 5.10 onwards. `5.8.8` is pretty old, but seems to still be about!

Answer (score 2):

I think, you should use Perl formats. Have a look at the [Perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html). You may want to use the `@*` format field in your case.

I extended your code in order to print the desired output at the end

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @M_array;
my @F_array;

open (my $input, "<", 'ssbn1898.txt');

while ( <$input> ) {

    chomp;

    my ( $name, $id ) = split ( /,/ ); 

    if ( $id eq "M" ) {
        push ( @M_array, $name );
    }
    else {
        push ( @F_array, $name ); 
    }
}
close ( $input );

unshift @M_array, 'M';
unshift @F_array, 'F';

my $namem; 
my $namef;

my $max = 0;

$max = (length($_) gt $max  ? length($_) : $max) for @M_array;
my $w = '@' . '<' x $max;

eval "
format STDOUT = 
$w @*
\$namem, \$namef 
.
";

while ( @M_array or @F_array) {

    $namem = shift @M_array || '';
    $namef = shift @F_array || '';

    write;

}
```

Comment: I think this would be much improved with an example.

Comment: @Sobrique Perl's `format` looks complicated (for C/C++ programmers). Did you ever use it successfully?

Comment: About 15 years ago, yes. Not since. (Which is part of why I was keen on an example :))

Comment: @Sobrique: Well, I normally do not create output with aligned columns on the command line. I would prefer to create some structured output and let another program do the formatting. 

Hmmm ...  that might have been a better answer at all;-)

Comment: Regarding your remark - you could perhaps do an `$namem = shift @M_array // '';` so you get an empty string if undefined.

Comment: Wow it works :-) But better add a comment that the first output doesn't use formatting. Ah, there is an issue with missing data? I tried `@m = ("a", "b"); @f = ("x", "y", "z");` and got only 2 rows of output.

Comment: @Wolf Yes, I found the issue, too and enhanced the code accordingly. And I removed the print statements.

Answer (score 1):

`join` is probably the simplest approach to take `tabs` will align your columns nicely.

```
join ( "\t", @array ),
```

Alternatively, perl allows formatting via [(s)printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html):

```
printf ( "%-10s %-10s", "first", "second" );
```

Or a more detailed ['format'](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html)

Given what you're trying to do is put your two arrays into columns though:

```perl
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $format = "%-10s\t%-10s\n";

my @M_array = qw ( M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 );
my @F_array = qw ( F1 F2 F3 );
my $maxrows = $#M_array > $#F_array ?  $#M_array : $#F_array; 

printf ( $format, "M", "F" );
for my $rownum ( 0..$maxrows ) { 
    printf ( $format, $M_array[$rownum] // '', $F_array[$rownum] // '' );

}
```

This will print a header row, and then loop through you arrays printing one line at a time. `//` is a conditional operation that tests if something is defined. It's only available in newer perls though*. In older versions `||` will do the trick - it's *almost* the same, but handles `''` and `0` slightly differently.

* Perl 5.10 onward, so is pretty safe, but worth mentioning because some system are still rocking around with perl 5.8 on them.

Comment: `printf` is of course easier to use than a `print sprintf` combination. I'm getting syntactic "errors", after correcting, there are again errors: "Use of uninitialized value..." maybe my Perl is too old (5.8.8)?

Comment: Yes. `//` is a perl 5.10 feature. `||` will work in 5.8.8 though. And yes, 5.8.8 is really old - it's officially end of life, being a 2008 release. (But you aren't the only one who uses it by any means)

Comment: Ok, I got it running now with perl 5.8.8. The problem with this answer is, that the SO syntax highlighter doesn't understand it. So it reads absolutely confusing. Maybe it would be better to add the `||` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You may format output with the [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) function, but there are some more problems to solve: What if the arrays don't have the same count of entries? For this, you need a place-holder. How much letters must fit into a column? How should it be aligned? Some code for illustration:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @m = (1, 2, 3);
my @f = (11, 22, 33, 44);

# calculate how many rows to display
my $max = @m;
if (@m < @f) {
    $max = @f;
}

# placeholder for missing data
my $none = '-';

# formatting 20 chars per column, left aligned
my $fmt = "%-20s%-20s\n";

# print header
print sprintf($fmt, "M", "F");

# print data rows
foreach my $i (0..$max-1) {
    print sprintf($fmt, ($m[$i] or $none), ($f[$i] or $none));
}
```

If you are interested in more sophisticated formatting (for instance center-aligned text), you should switch to the [special formatting capabilities](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html) Perl provides for report generation.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from @HunterMcMillen

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature "say";

local $, = "\t";   # separator when printing list

my $i = (@F_array > @M_array) ? $#F_array : $#M_array;

say qw(M F);
say $M_array[$i] //"", $F_array[$i] //"" for 0 .. $i;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess Text::Table is the required module which comes with the perl distribution(just need to install).Go through the below documentation -

[Documentation of Text::Table](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Text-Table-1.130/lib/Text/Table.pm)

You need to pass the content as array to the add() method and it will do the wonders for you.